# Self Join Issue, incorrect syntax near 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, self-join

I have a database with shipped quantities by month from January 2017 to present. I want to put yearly shipped numbers in unique columns by year (for the purpose of manipulating PowerBI visualziations).

The first query (without yearly columns) works:

```
SELECT   
    FORMAT(frcst.InvDate, 'yyyyMM') AS period_name
    , MONTH(frcst.InvDate) AS month_num
    , YEAR(frcst.InvDate) AS year_num
    , frcst.LineCode
    , frcst.ClassCode
    , cc_type
    , rank
    , keycust1
    , keycust2
    , keycust3
    , sales1
    , sales2
    , sales3
    , SUM(GrossSales) AS gross_sales
    , SUM (QtyShip + ( (QtyOrd - QtyShip) * 0.25) ) AS frcst_qty
FROM 
    FrcstFactTbl frcst
JOIN 
    account_hierarchy_lu account ON frcst.AccountNumber = account.account_number
JOIN 
    cc_type_lu cct ON frcst.ClassCode = cct.class_code
JOIN 
    pop_code_lu pop ON frcst.PartNumber = pop.PartNumber
GROUP BY 
    InvDate, frcst.LineCode, frcst.ClassCode, cc_type, rank, 
    keycust1, keycust2, keycust3, sales1, sales2, sales3
ORDER BY 
    InvDate
```

I am getting an error (with yearly columns) with the query:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near '2017'

```
SELECT   
    MONTH(frcst.InvDate) AS mnth
    , frcst.LineCode
    , frcst.ClassCode
    , cc_type
    , rank
    , keycust1
    , keycust2
    , keycust3
    , sales1
    , sales2
    , sales3
    , SUM(ship2017.GrossSales) AS 2017gross_sales
    , SUM(ship2017.QtyShip + ((ship2017.QtyOrd - ship2017.QtyShip) * 0.25)) AS 2017_frcst_qty
    , SUM(ship2018.GrossSales) AS 2018gross_sales
    , SUM(ship2018.QtyShip + ((ship2018.QtyOrd - ship2018.QtyShip) * 0.25)) AS 2018_frcst_qty
    , SUM(ship2019.GrossSales) AS 2019_gross_sales
    , SUM(ship2019.QtyShip + ((ship2019.QtyOrd - ship2019.QtyShip) * 0.25)) AS 2019_frcst_qty
    , SUM(ship2020.GrossSales) AS ship2020_gross_sales
    , SUM(ship2020.QtyShip + ((ship2020.QtyOrd - ship2017.QtyShip) * 0.25)) AS 2020_frcst_qty
FROM 
    FrcstFactTbl frcst
JOIN 
    account_hierarchy_lu account ON frcst.AccountNumber = account.account_number
JOIN 
    cc_type_lu cct ON frcst.ClassCode = cct.class_code
JOIN 
    pop_code_lu pop ON frcst.PartNumber = pop.PartNumber
JOIN 
    FrcstFactTbl ship2017 ON frcst.mnth = ship2017.mnth
                          AND frcst.LineCode = ship2017.LineCode
                          AND frcst.ClassCode = ship2017.ClassCode
                          AND frcst.keycust3 = ship2017.keycust3
JOIN 
    FrcstFactTbl ship2018 ON frcst.mnth = ship2018.mnth
                          AND frcst.LineCode = ship2018.LineCode
                          AND frcst.ClassCode = ship2018.ClassCode
                          AND frcst.keycust3 = ship2018.keycust3
JOIN 
    FrcstFactTbl ship2019 ON frcst.mnth = ship2019.mnth
                          AND frcst.LineCode = ship2019.LineCode
                          AND frcst.ClassCode = ship2019.ClassCode
                          AND frcst.keycust3 = ship2019.keycust3
JOIN 
    FrcstFactTbl ship2020 ON frcst.mnth = ship2020.mnth
                          AND frcst.LineCode = ship2020.LineCode
                          AND frcst.ClassCode = ship2020.ClassCode
                          AND frcst.keycust3 = ship2020.keycust3
WHERE 
    YEAR(ship2017.InvDate) = '2017'
    AND YEAR(ship2018.InvDate) = '2018'
    AND YEAR(ship2019.InvDate) = '2019'
    AND YEAR(ship2020.InvDate) = '2020'
GROUP BY 
    mnth, frcst.LineCode, frcst.ClassCode, cc_type, rank, 
    keycust1, keycust2, keycust3, sales1, sales2, sales3
ORDER BY 
    mnth
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: [Identifiers cannot start with a number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15), either put square brackets around them e.g.  [2020_frcst_qty]`, or start them with a letter.

Comment: That worked, but now I have another issue. I am getting an "Invalid column name 'mnth' for every time that field is referenced in the Self Joins. I defined the month of the initial table in the SELECT statement. Where can I define month for the tables used in the self joins?

Comment: The **only** place you can use a column alias (which is what `mnth` is) is in the `order by` clause. Everywhere else you have to use the computation `MONTH(frcst.InvDate)` or else compute it in a sub-query.

Comment: BTW - you should really ask a new question for that as the question you asked has been answered, and its not the intention of a SO question to be a complete debugging session for you.

Answer (score 1):

**First Option:**

Replace `2017gross_sales`, `2018gross_sales` and `2019gross_sales` with `gross_sales_2017`, `gross_sales_2018` and `gross_sales_2019` respectively.

It is best practice to start column names with an alpha character.

**Second Option:**

as per @DaleK comment you can use square bracket as well like `[2017gross_sales]`

**Third Option:**

You can use double quote `"` like `"2017gross_sales"`

Comment: More accurate if you cite (and reference) the specification as to what is and isn't allowed. For example underscore (`_`) is perfectly OK and not a letter.